# How do I get my QProgressDialog to show up when I don't know how long it will take?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I am using `subprocess.call` to run a command prompt command that takes a while (>5 minutes) to run:

```
subprocess.call([command, param1, param2], cwd=cwdDir)
```

I want to use a QProgressDialog to show that this command is running. I did this:

```
        progressDialog = QProgressDialog("Executing...", "", 0, 0)
        progressDialog.setCancelButton(None)
        progressBar = QProgressBar(progressDialog)
        progressBar.setMinimum(0)
        progressBar.setMaximum(0)
        progressDialog.setBar(progressBar)
        progressDialog.show()
        subprocess.call([command, param1, param2], cwd=cwdDir)
        progressDialog.close()
```

When I run my program, this is what shows up:

[image]

After a while, my commands finish executing and the window closes. How do I get it so that you can see the `QProgressBar` in the window?

Comment: Do I understand your question correctly - the problem is that the progress-dialog doesn't show up?

Comment: @GeorgSchölly It doesn't show up completely. What shows up is in the picture, the dialog shows up, but the stuff inside it does not

Comment: It looks like `subprocess.call()` is a blocking function call. Qt can't paint anything (like your progress bar) if you block the event loop like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Qthread so program's event loop is not blocked. And increase the value of the progress bar either by a timer or read information from subprocess.call or just show the busy icon in the process bar.